# AWS SQL Database automatic backup and restore

Tags: c#, sql-server, amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using currently AWS RDS for my sql connection.

Having database DB1

Now I want every day automatic backup on 10PM IST  of DB1 and  and it should be restored immediately as another database DB2.

How can I start and what is the process needs to be followed for this?

I am using ASP .NET MVC ,SQL,C# as technologies.

Thanks in advance

Comment: setup a job in SQL to do just that

Answer (score 1):

aws RDS provides automatic backups which can be retained (for a week) and restored.

Or you can take manual db snapshots and then restore from them. 
To automate the process you can use scheduled event trigger on cloudwatch (in your case every night for backup and morning for restore) and run a lambda function to do the backup and then the restore. Please Refer the Documentations from AWS:

[Backing Up and Restoring Amazon RDS DB Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.BackupRestore.html)

[Automated Backups and Database Snapshots](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#automated-backups-database-snapshots)

[Using AWS Lambda Function with Scheduled Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-create-function.html)

Comment: Those aren't automatic backups. These are file system snapshots. There's a huge difference - a volume snapshot contains the data as it was at the time of the snapshot, open transactions, dirty data and all. The server will have to go into recovery to roll back the open transactions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the update. yes there are differences but  These are the options provided as per aws documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Mentioned in comment I would like you to first know what you require as db snapshot and db backup are two different things:

DB Snapshot is think about it as a Polaroid picture. You’re out, and you’re having fun with your friends, and somebody snaps a Polaroid or an Instagram or whatever. It’s just that. ***It’s an instant point in time***.

Unless you get into some really, really specifics on storage array snapshots, you could end up in a state that’s called “***crash inconsistency***”

A DB Backup on other hand can actually talk to those applications, make sure that all of that data that’s residing in memory be written to disk. That way, you can be sure that your server, if you have to *restore it*, is *in a crash consistent state* and **you can be assured that your data is available**.

Now as Per [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html) You can specify backup windows (autobackup) but it will deteriorate performance a bit of your DB.

Then you can Restore it via API Call or AWS CLI from linux or unix :

```
aws rds restore-db-instance-to-point-in-time \
    --source-db-instance-identifier mysourcedbinstance \
    --target-db-instance-identifier mytargetdbinstance \
    --restore-time 2009-10-14T23:45:00.000Z
```

Or if you want to use API you can use the Amazon RDS API `RestoreDBInstanceToPointInTime` function with the following parameters:

- `SourceDBInstanceIdentifier` = *mysourcedbinstance*
- `TargetDBInstanceIdentifier` = *mytargetdbinstance*
- `RestoreTime` = *2013-10-14T23:45:00.000Z*

You can Refer [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIT.html) for the same